# What is the MyGameProgress class?

Tags: android, google-play-games, google-api-client

I'm trying to make a game where I store a high score.

The "Implementing Sign-in on Android" link:

https://developers.google.com/games/services/training/signin#signing_the_player_in_at_startup

says to use the MyGameProgress class to save the score, achievements, etc..
However, I get a "cannot resolve symbol MyGameProgress" when I try to declare a variable as a MyGameProgress 
(ex. MyGameProgress mGameProgress = new MyGameProgress() )

Anybody have a clue ?

below is my MainActivity.java file:

---

```
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.games.Games;
import com.google.example.games.basegameutils.BaseGameUtils;



public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    int Score = 0;

    GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    MyGameProgress mGameProgress = new MyGameProgress();


    private static int RC_SIGN_IN = 9001;
    private boolean mResolvingConnectionFailure = false;
    private boolean mAutoStartSignInFlow = true;
    private boolean mSignInClicked = false;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);




    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        if (mResolvingConnectionFailure) {
            // Already resolving
            return;
        }

        // If the sign in button was clicked or if auto sign-in is enabled,
        // launch the sign-in flow


        if (mSignInClicked || mAutoStartSignInFlow) {
            mAutoStartSignInFlow = false;
            mSignInClicked = false;
            mResolvingConnectionFailure = true;

            // Attempt to resolve the connection failure using BaseGameUtils.
            // The R.string.signin_other_error value should reference a generic
            // error string in your strings.xml file, such as "There was
            // an issue with sign in, please try again later."
            if (!BaseGameUtils.resolveConnectionFailure(this,
                    mGoogleApiClient, connectionResult,
                    RC_SIGN_IN, "R.string.signin_other_error")) {
                mResolvingConnectionFailure = false;
            }
        }

        // Put code here to display the sign-in button
    }




    public void increaseScore(View view) {
        Score = Score + 1;
        TextView ScoreTextV = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);

        ScoreTextV.setText(Integer.toString(Score));
    };

    public void FinishGame(View view) {
        //Games.Leaderboards.submitScore(getApiClient(),
        //        getString(R.string.leaderboard_high_score), Score);


        // when user finishes level:
        mGameProgress.addScore(userScore);
        mGameProgress.addAchievement(fooAchievement);
        mGameProgress.addAchievement(barAchievement);
        if (mGoogleApiClient != null && mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            mGameProgress.save(mGoogleApiClient);
        }


    }
}
```

---

in my build.gradle (module.app) I have included this under dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile project(':BaseGameUtils')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
    //compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-games:6.5.87'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.5.+'
```

---

in my AndroidManifest.xml I included:

```
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.games.APP_ID"
        android:value="@string/app_id" />

    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

---

I also imported the BaseGameUtils module.

---

for convenience, Here's the code snippet from the "Implementing Sign-in on Android" link I provided above:

```
MyGameProgress mGameProgress = ....;

// when user finishes level:
mGameProgress.addScore(userScore);
mGameProgress.addAchievement(fooAchievement);
mGameProgress.addAchievement(barAchievement);
if (mGoogleApiClient != null && mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
    mGameProgress.save(mGoogleApiClient);
}

@Override
protected void onConnected() {
    // sign in successful, so save progress if we have any.  
    if (mGameProgress != null) {
        mGameProgress.save(mGoogleApiClient);
    }

    // ...
}
```

if I need to create the MyGameProgress class myself I don't know how to create the 'save' method so that it would save the high score to the game services cloud.

---

I also saw something about 'snapshots' for saving game progress.  Do you think that's a better way of doing it.  Should I research doing it that way instead ?

Comment: Did you add the appropriate libraries to your project and import the right classes?

Comment: thanks for responding.  I have just added info on what I added to my build.gradle and AndroidManifest files.  Hopefully that helps you get a better picture of what might be wrong.

Comment: I imported the BaseGameUtils module.

Comment: I have also posted the MainActivity imports.

Comment: As I understand the docs you linked, It seems to be a class which you have to create yourself.

Comment: thanks JonasCz.  I had a feeling that's what it was too.  Not sure how to go about it though.  Especially the 'save' method of the class.

Comment: I saw something about 'snapshots' for saving game progress.  Do you think I should do it that way instead ?

Comment: Yes, you could, but I don't know which would be best in your case. You should probably just do whatever is easyest.

Comment: I was able to make it work.

Comment: I was able to make it work with the statement:               Games.Leaderboards.submitScore(mGoogleApiClient,
                    getString(R.string.leaderboard_high_score), Score);    Originally some documentation said to use Games.Leaderboards.submitScore(getApiClient(),
        //        getString(R.string.leaderboard_high_score), Score);  but the  getApiClient() part was making it not work.  Replacing it with a google api client variable worked (mGoogleApiClient)

Comment: That's good. Why not answer your own question so that everyone can benefit ?

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that MyGameProgress (which has a 'save' method) was a class that the documentation wanted me to create.
I was able instead, however, to just use the Games.Leaderboards.submitScore method.

I was able to make it work with the statement: 
Games.Leaderboards.submitScore(mGoogleApiClient, getString(R.string.leaderboard_high_score), Score);

Note:
Originally some documentation said to use 
Games.Leaderboards.submitScore(getApiClient(), getString(R.string.leaderboard_high_score), Score);

but the getApiClient() part was making it not work. 
It worked after I Replaced it with a 
GoogleApiClient variable mGoogleApiClient.